# WinAPI Named Pipe location

Tags: c, windows, winapi, named-pipes

```
HANDLE pipe = CreateFile( L"\\\\.\\pipe\\my_pipe",
                              GENERIC_READ, // only need read access
                              FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                              NULL,
                              OPEN_EXISTING,
                              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                              NULL );
```

I'm new to win api and i'd like to know where is the "my_pipe" file created on the hard disk?
I can't find it anywhere near the binary or sources

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows doesn't follow the UNIX philosophy "everything is a file", so the named objects you create with the kernel APIs aren't files, but are objects in various NT objects namespaces. You can see them with tools like [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx).

You may want to have a look at the article about the [object manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_%28Windows%29) in Windows.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I'm sorry, but that's a stupid comment. The "everything is a file" idea is technically debatable (e.g. the `/proc` FS to me feels like a horrible API), and Dave Cutler (the main designer between the NT kernel structure) is undoubtedly a *great* OS designer. I appreciate and use mainly Linux, but that doesn't mean that other choices in OS design aren't sound.

Comment: it was a joke, of course it was a stupid comment :)
i can't stand win things that's why i tend to make stupid jokes :)
who am i to criticize such decisions?...